# Size limit of content on a single note in Notes app

Tags: macos, notes.app

Using [Notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notes_(Apple)) 4.8.1 app on macOS Big Sur (and in iOS/iPadOS).

What is the size limit for text content on a single note in the Notes app?

I am writing page multiple pages in printed length. I wonder if I am going to hit some limit.

Comment: I just attached a 10 MB video to a note. Are you concerned with attachment size, text length or something else? I don’t think there’s a specific limit for iCloud or the copy / paste buffer and the only limit I recall is Pages documents over 500 MB sometimes ask to be saved as a package and not just one file https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202887 - even then it’s still the same “document”

Comment: @bmike Text length, typing in the note window.

Comment: My hunch is you can’t copy and paste enough plain text to choke it - will be interesting who is the most dedicated tester of this

Comment: I don't think you will ever receive a notification saying "Character limit reached" but you might get stopped at some point because it lags too much. And this depends on many criteria - RAM, Apps opened (size+number), Storage, etc.